# Get element by ID in jquery

Tags: jquery

So basically, I want to know whether there is a function in jQuery that is similar to getElementById of vanilla javascript. The problem of using $('#' + id) is that the string concatenation doesn't seems to be good coding style.

I can definitely add my own helper method but I am just wondering whether there is already something in jQuery.

Comment: there is not... another option is `$(document.getElementById(id))`.... but seriously what is wrong with a string concatenation?

Comment: *"The problem of using `$('#' + id)` is that the string concatenation doesn't seems to be good coding style."* String concatenation is the only way to build dynamic selectors, and there are valid use cases for that. I wouldn't worry too much about it. I assume you are not doing something ingenious like `var id = this.id; $('#'+id)....`.

Comment: @FelixKling I guess I was oversensitive. Basically, I am writing a UI tool and the id shall be extracted from another element's attribute in order to establish some relation. I was thinking about things like sql injection and felt that a more procedural way to write code is better than assembling a string. But in client-side script it shouldn't be a problem unless someone intentionally want a scrambled page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually works:

```
var id="myTextBox";
alert ($(eval(id)).val());
```

html:

```
<input type='textbox' id="myTextBox" value="hola mundo"></input>
```

And you're not using string concat **but**:
**I wouldn't use it or encourage to under any circunstance, string concat is the way to go in this case I think.**

More about eval():
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

More information related here:
[Why is using the JavaScript eval function a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/86513/462889)

Answer (score 2):

It is as simple as the one you wrote. If you have an element with the id 'divInfo' then you can select the element by using `$('#divInfo')`. Its just plain CSS selector.